# install a pole to hold telephone line 3ft in air of the house?

Tags: electrical-panel

I would like to install a pole/mast/pipe on side of house going above roof 3ft. It needs to hold phone line from street and maybe cable line also. Not sure what size galvenized pipe to use or an antenna mast or something. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You should talk to your utility company about this before doing anything yourself.

Comment: You also may be increasing your risk of a lightening strike.

Comment: @bib Agreed -- one more reason to have someone who knows the building codes to install this & install a lightning arrestor as well.    Meanwhile -- Hey, Karliano, what is the existing state of the cables?